# How can I write an efficient code that creates a calendar in R?

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data.table

My objective is to write a more efficient code that creates a calendar that distributes dealer's customers to different days so that:

1. All days have at least `min` customers per day and (`min` depends on the dealer)
2. All days have at most `max` customers per day and (`max` depends on the dealer)
3. Whenever a customer is moved to a different day, he should be moved to the closest one possible (don't bother about ties - if the distance is the same then 1 day before or 1 day after is the same)

Example:

```
dealer_id  <- rep(c("ABC123","DEF234","GHJ456"), each = 4)
date       <- as.Date(rep(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04"), times = 3))
cust_pos_1 <- c("MCA1", "MCA2", "MCA3", "MCA4", "MCA5", "MCA6", NA, NA, "MCA9", "MCA10", "MCA11", "MCA12")
cust_pos_2 <- c("MCB1", "MCB2", NA, NA, "MCB5", NA, NA, NA, "MCB9", NA, "MCB11", NA)
cust_pos_3 <- c("MCC1", "MCC2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "MCC9", NA, NA, NA)

df         <- data.frame(dealer_id, date, cust_pos_1, cust_pos_2, cust_pos_3)

settings   <- data.frame(dealer_id = c("ABC123","DEF234","GHJ456"), min_daily = c(2, 0, 1), max_daily = c(3, 1, 2))
```

Gives us the input data and the dealer settings:

```
dealer_id date       cust_pos_1 cust_pos_2 cust_pos_3
ABC123    2018-01-01 MCA1       MCB1       MCC1
ABC123    2018-01-02 MCA2       MCB2       MCC2
ABC123    2018-01-03 MCA3       NA         NA
ABC123    2018-01-04 MCA4       NA         NA
DEF234    2018-01-01 MCA5       MCB5       NA
DEF234    2018-01-02 MCA6       NA         NA
DEF234    2018-01-03 NA         NA         NA
DEF234    2018-01-04 NA         NA         NA
GHJ456    2018-01-01 MCA9       MCB9       MCC9
GHJ456    2018-01-02 MCA10      NA         NA
GHJ456    2018-01-03 MCA11      MCB11      NA
GHJ456    2018-01-04 MCA12      NA         NA

dealer_id min_daily max_daily
ABC123    2         3
DEF234    0         1
GHJ456    1         2
```

and the output data after the code runs should look like this:

```
dealer_id date       cust_pos_1 cust_pos_2 cust_pos_3
ABC123    2018-01-01 MCA1       MCB1       NA
ABC123    2018-01-02 MCA2       MCB2       NA
ABC123    2018-01-03 MCA3       MCC1       NA
ABC123    2018-01-04 MCA4       MCC2       NA
DEF234    2018-01-01 MCA5       NA         NA
DEF234    2018-01-02 MCA6       NA         NA
DEF234    2018-01-03 MCB5       NA         NA
DEF234    2018-01-04 NA         NA         NA
GHJ456    2018-01-01 MCA9       MCB9       NA
GHJ456    2018-01-02 MCA10      MCC9       NA
GHJ456    2018-01-03 MCA11      MCB11      NA
GHJ456    2018-01-04 MCA12      NA         NA
```

Because of the settings - the customers had to be re-distributed according to the above rules.

There is a rule for the settings table as well! The difference between `min` and `max` is always going to be 1.

It's trivial to say that there is more than 1 way for this to be solved as the fact that we don't care whether the customer is moved x days before of x days after means that we can get different (and better!) solutions.

Now. That being said, I've solved it using a loop that takes ages to run (my data frames are massive - I've got to create this calendar for 5 years and for 150 dealers with hundreds of customers).

My question is: Is there a way to do it using maybe `dplyr` or `data.table` or something else so that it runs faster?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your working code and ask for improvements as opposed to asking for someone to provide a solution for scratch.

Comment: I can't really share the code as it's long. Should I re-phrase the question to ask how to it or should I share the idea of the code and people can just comment on that?

Comment: based on settings, ABC123 can handle a max of 3, then why do you shift MCC1 and MCC2 down?

Comment: Because the min for ABC123 is 2. The code has to handle firstly the the min is satisfied and then that the max is not violated

Answer (score 2):

The code bellow will fill out the empty space within acceptable cells from the customers that are outside the range of max_daily setting. However, one potential problem may be that the code relocate customers far away from their original date.
The code provided is compatible with dplyr pipe operator and is really quick.

```
calendar_sort <- function(df){ 


    df <- as.data.frame(df)
    # 
    nr <- nrow(df)
    nc <- ncol(df)
    nc_p <- nc - 2 #if you have more than 2 col for DealerID and Date, change this 

    ttl_cn <- sum(!is.na(df[,3:nc])) # total count of non_NAs 
    mx <- ceiling(ttl_cn / nr)
    rng_nnac <- sum(!is.na(df[,3:(2+mx)])) # count of non-NAs within the range

    left_overs <- df[,(mx+3):nc]
    left_overs <- left_overs[!is.na(left_overs)]

    lo_c <- length(left_overs) # leftover non-NA count
    ttl_s <-  (nr*nc_p) # total number of cells (total space)

    df[,(mx+3):nc] <- NA
    A <- c(left_overs, rep(NA, ttl_s - rng_nnac -lo_c))
    df[is.na(df)] <- A

    B <- df[,3:nc]
    B <- B[!is.na(B)] 
    B <- c(B, rep(NA, ttl_s - length(B)))
    df[,3:nc] <- B

    return(df)
}

result <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(Dealer) %>% do(calendar_sort(.))
```